# How to access shared preferences inside object

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin, gson, sharedpreferences

I am trying to access my gson json shared preferences inside object. I dont know how to access it.
This is my code for accessing shared preferences inside a fragment.

```
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = sharedPreferences.getString("loclists", "")
        val type = object: TypeToken<MutableList<LatLng>>() {}.type

        if(json == null || json == "")
            loclists = mutableListOf<LatLng>()



        else
            loclists = gson.fromJson(json, type)
```

````
    ```
````

This is my object class. I am trying to access the shared preferences inside the `calculateTheDistance` function. I am getting error when I type requireContext().

````
    val PREFS_FILENAME = "com.app.app.prefs"
    private var loclistsDT= mutableListOf<LatLng>()



   fun calculateTheDistance(locationList: MutableList<LatLng>): String {


        val sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, 0)
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = sharedPreferences.getString("loclists", "")
        val type = object : TypeToken<MutableList<LatLng>>() {}.type

        if (json == null || json == "")
            loclistsDT = mutableListOf<LatLng>()
        else
            loclistsDT = gson.fromJson(json, type)
       

 if(locListsDT.size > 1){
            val meters =
                SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(locListsDT.first(), locListsDT.last())
            val kilometers = meters / 1000
            return DecimalFormat("#.##").format(kilometers)
        }
        return "0.00"
    }

} ```
````

Comment: `requireContext` returns the parents context , what you need is `application`

Comment: I tried. But still getting error

Comment: Can you tell what error ?

Comment: when typing `application` does not show up. It is shown in red after typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `calculateTheDistance` pass context of activity if you cannot access `application`, this is how

```
fun calculateTheDistance(mContext : Context , locationList: MutableList<LatLng>): String {


        val sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, 0)
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = sharedPreferences.getString("loclists", "")
        val type = object : TypeToken<MutableList<LatLng>>() {}.type

        if (json == null || json == "")
            loclistsDT = mutableListOf<LatLng>()
        else
            loclistsDT = gson.fromJson(json, type)
       

 if(locListsDT.size > 1){
            val meters =
                SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(locListsDT.first(), locListsDT.last())
            val kilometers = meters / 1000
            return DecimalFormat("#.##").format(kilometers)
        }
        return "0.00"
    }

}
```

and for using this add `requireContext` in your parameters if from fragment OR `this` if from activity.